# What kind of JS data structure internals represent?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at [celebrate.js](https://github.com/arb/celebrate/blob/master/lib/celebrate.js).
Object internals

```
internals
{
  DEFAULT_ERROR_ARGS: { celebrated: true },
  DEFAULT_ERRORS_OPTS: { statusCode: 400 },
  DEFAULT_CELEBRATE_OPTS: { mode: 'partial' }
}
```

Different actions are applied to this object later.

```
internals.validateSegment = (segment) => (spec, joiConfig) => {
  const finalValidate = (req) => spec.validateAsync(req[segment], joiConfig);
  finalValidate.segment = segment;
  return finalValidate;
};
```

What do internals represent?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. If you add more elements to an object it's still an object.

Comment: @GuyIncognito oK,CAN YOU explain what does validateSegment do?

Comment: Not without studying the entire code of the library, which I'm not going to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `internals` object holds a set of default options (called *segments* here). They are accessed by their identifiers `DEFAULT_ERROR_ARGS`, `DEFAULT_ERRORS_OPTS` and `DEFAULT_CELEBRATE_OPTS`.

The segments are object themselves, that contain options (e.g. `celebrated`) and their default values (e.g. `true`).

All segments of `internals` can be passed to and validated by `validateSegment()`. Each property is defined by a key (here: `spec`) and a value (here: `joiConfig`). For each specification the function `validateAsync()` is called and the result is assigned to `finalValidate`.

The function `validateSegment()` can be called for individual segments. See function `maybeValidateBody()` in the code that you linked to, for example:

```
internals.maybeValidateBody = (segment) => {
  const validateOne = internals.validateSegment(segment); <-- Called here!
  return (spec, joiConfig) => {
  ...
```

In the above code block, the `segment` is passed to `internals.validateSegment()` and the return value is assigned to `validateOne`, for example.

Comment: validateSegment actions will be applied to each of them?

Comment: Yes, it can be called for all segments individually. I've edited my answer.